# how to exclude or replace the jackson from spring boot pom

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I'm using spring boot 1.5.12.RELEASE. It is working fine and I'm able to build the project.

But now I want to upgrade the spring boot version to 1.5.15.RELEASE. and I'm getting below error.

> Plugin
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.15.RELEASE or
>   one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.15.RELEASE:
>   Failure to transfer
>   com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.8.11.20180608

I have my repository so I can't download the file from maven repo. I'm having the version for jackson 2.8.11.20180217. I don't have the version 2.8.11.20180608.

So is there any way to use the version 2.8.11.20180217 instead of  2.8.11.20180608 or not use jackson.

Answer (score 8):

Add the maven dependency for the jackson version you want and exclude jackson dependency for all the modules that need id :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Try to check which dependencies requires jackson. Maybe you could update your question to show your pom.xml

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you are inheriting the jar from some of your dependencies.
First, search where is the dependency that you need to exclude with:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

The `-Dverbose` option will show all dependencies, even the ones removed.

Read [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) for more info

Then, when you find it, select the dependency that has that inside of it, and exclude with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>xxx</version>
        <exclusions> <!-- This is what you need to add -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>theGroupIdToExclude</groupId>
                <artifactId>theArtifactIdToExclude</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I'm using eclipse inbuilt maven. So how can I run that command?

Comment: you have to launch this with windows / linux console. Browse to the folder where your pom is, then launch that command